# How to append ajax data into select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using select2 dropdown and I am trying to build it as such that it dynamically displays the leads based on the JSON response.

As u can see in the image below, the text inserted correctly returns a JSON array, however, select2 is not capable of assigning the results into options. Therefore, I am literally quite stuck on what to do from here.

[image]
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/v14Qo.pnghere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v14Qo.png)

I already tried setting a variable equal to the selectbox and appending the data in there, but my editor indicates that the code will  be unreachable.

**Create.tpl - contains front-end code**

```
{literal}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.select2lead').select2({
            minimumInputLength: 3,
            ajax: {
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/modules/support/ajax.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
            }
        });

        $('#select2lead').select2({
            tags: true,
            minimumInputLength: 3,
            ajax: {
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/modules/support/ajax.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                data: function (params) {
                    var query = {
                        search: params.term
                    };
                    // Query parameters will be ?search=[term]&type=public
                    return query;
                },
                processResults: function (data) {
                    var select2lead = $('#select2lead');
                    // Tranforms the top-level key of the response object from 'items' to 'results'
                    return {
                        results: data.items
                    }
                    // var option = new Option(data.name, data.id, true, true);
                    // select2lead.append(option).trigger('change');
                }
            }
        });

        $('#summernote').summernote({
            height: 150,
            minHeight: null,
            maxHeight: null,
            focus: true
        });
    })

</script>
{/literal}
```

**ajax.php - handles the search term and returns JSON**

```
<?php
require_once('../../config.php');

$login = new Login();
if (!$login->checkLogin()) {
    echo lang($_SESSION['language'], "INSUFFICIENT_RIGHTS");
    exit();
}

$db = new Database();

$query = "
        SELECT
            LeadID AS lead_id,
            REPLACE(CONCAT_WS(' ', LeadInitials, LeadInsertion, LeadLastName), '  ', ' ') AS name,
            REPLACE(CONCAT_WS(' ', LeadStreet, LeadStreetNumber, LeadNumberAdjective), '  ', ' ') AS address,
            LeadZiPCode AS zipcode,
            LeadCity AS city
        FROM
            `LeadTBL`
        WHERE
            LeadID > 0
        AND
            LeadLastName LIKE :leadName
        ORDER BY
            LeadLastName
        ASC
    ";

$binds = array(':leadName' => $_GET['term'].'_%'.'_%');
$result = $db->select($query, $binds);
$json = [];

foreach ($result as $row){
    $json[] = ['id'=>$row['lead_id'], 'name'=>$row['name']];
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: In your JSON data, you need to have `id` and `text`, you got `id` and `name` right now, no? Try to change it to begin with :)

Comment: @MickaelLeger I have it as id and name because those are the values from the database table:

REPLACE(CONCAT_WS(' ', LeadInitials, LeadInsertion, LeadLastName), '  ', ' ') AS name,

LeadID AS lead_id,

foreach ($result as $row){
 $json[] = ['id'=>$row['lead_id'], 'name'=>$row['name']];
}

Comment: Sure, but if you read the Select2 documentation (https://select2.org/data-sources/formats) your data need to have this form : `[{"id" : ..., "text":...}, ... ]` so just try this : `$json[] = ['id'=>$row['lead_id'], 'text'=>$row['name']];`

Comment: @MickaelLeger I see. Thanks for the reminder. I'll try and get back to you. EDIT: Still will not work, as in, it simply has changed the JSON response from id & name into id & text. Still cannot create options for the dropdown.

Comment: take a object (which is your data) and update it with new value, later call change event should update the values in select2, try this way

Comment: @Adrian I have that in this function: https://hastebin.com/ovikaviceq.js

Comment: @JustinBoxem see the docs https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items

Comment: @Adrian I already have looked there before; Hence the option / select2 append at the bottom of the script; I found it there at the docs.

Comment: When I use Select2, I work an other way : I get a function "init_form" that do an Ajax call and send me back a response with my data (with the format id / text, then in the success part I init my input as Select2 : `$('#myinput').select2({data: response, multiple: true});`, so when I change my data I just do an other init with the new data to update my input list...don't know if you can try this way

Comment: @MickaelLeger Perhaps a hastebin / pastebin snippet can help visually explain?

Comment: @JustinBoxem just to be sure before, your problem is that you can't display your data in your Select2 input according to your query, right? Or it works but you can't update the list after you add new data?

Comment: @MickaelLeger I am not AJAX proficient, but from what I can see in my console's network tab where it displays my JSON objects, basically the system can retrieve all database objects according to what I type in and give to the query. However, appearantly, it is unable to bind the returned JSON object as options to the select2, simply returning "No results found". (See the imgur image I posted in my question to see the network output. NOTE: By now "name" is changed into "text", but nevertheless the options are not created & added to the select2.

Comment: @JustinBoxem you are adding data at the end of json, right ? or maybe I am wrong here, I means modify json in same order to get same sorting in select2

Comment: @JustinBoxem Try to check this link if it works : https://jsfiddle.net/u82u7tfu/12/, this is how I use Select2 if it can help

Comment: @Adrian See: https://hastebin.com/muwovojije.php

Comment: @MickaelLeger: That uses predefined options; I need my select2 to remain empty until you have atleast typed 3 words, then it fires the query, which results JSON array with objects retrieved from database. (See https://i.imgur.com/RTL9lRx.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue resolved. Turns out I had to disable "more"; See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/select2/4mDifie32t0/jdJl8KIFN0EJ

Regarding the final code that actually pastes the results into the dropdown properly, see:

```
    $('.select2lead').select2({
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        ajax: {
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/modules/support/ajax.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    term: params.term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: data,
                    more: false
                };
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Justin I made a little demo to show append feature, https://anirugu.github.io/ques1.html nevermind if your problem is already fixed.